# Rails 4 : ConnectionTimeoutError on heroku basic plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

We are working on a [simple Rails 4 webapp](http://www.lasai.it), hosted by Heroku with the free plan.

Recently, we are experiencing some `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` - one every few days - and we don't really understand the reasons behind it.

You may want to have a look at the full stack [here](http://jsbin.com/qolelimu/1/edit?output).

We know Heroku sets a pool limit of 20 connections to the Postgres db, and this is most likely the the reason why the exception is thrown. This was our guess:

We are using Herku scheduler to launch a rake task every hour and, since that task queries the database, the problem could lie in the fact that those connections are not released from the pool after being used. So we tried to put everything inside a block:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do

  #code with queries

end
```

But this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Do you have better suggestions / explanations?

Any help and/or insight is greatly appreciated, also on how we should debug this problem.

---

PS: We also tried to add the following code in a dedicated initializer, but it didn't solve the problem

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL']      || 20
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Comment: you only have 1 process? Remember that if you have sidekick or something running they have to share the 20 connections...

Comment: We don't use Sidekiq, but we use the Heroku scheduler to call a rake, once every hour. That requires few queries... could it be the point?

Comment: hm, depends on your user load...  the rake tasks and the errors occur on the same time?

Comment: The user load in not that high - we never had 20 users at the same time. Anyway, I cannot get the precise timing of the error because of the "heroku logs" problem

Comment: you tried `heroku logs --num <some big number>` right?

Comment: Yes, but it was still not enough...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55161/discussion-between-abramodj-and-joni).

Comment: try to use https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout . and may be that will help

Comment: Thanks @ParitoshPiplewar, your suggestion is really good: it doesn't solve the problem, but at least it should avoid the crash.

Comment: Did you consider lowering the pool size of your application? If you set it to 20, your Sidekiq process may not get enough connections. Setting it to 5 should suffice, if you don't have a crazy high concurrency.

Comment: Cool , if no answer would come-up i will put that comment as answer with more detail. ;)

Comment: this is unicorn server right?  if so, can you provide your unicorn.rb file for the relevant before_fork/after_fork blocks

Comment: @blotto : No we don't have any unicorn.rb. We're using the standard Heroku server ( which should be Thin or Webrick )

Answer (score 5):

In my experience these issues will come up on basic Heroku plans. There are a number of ways to mitigate the frequency without added cost.  But you will never get to 0% occurrance with the basic/hobby stack.

Here's why in my experience.. until you hit 'premium-yanari' you wont get High Availability.  You can get 99.95% expected uptime vs the free 99.5%.  Doens't sound like much, but Heroku charges $150 extra for a reason (compared to the 'standard-yanari' plan).

After all the optimizations with connection pooling, reaping frequency, and forking, if your process cannot reach the database server you'll get a timeout.  If this is the only cause, it will happen very infrequently, which may be your case.  Only until I upgraded to 'premium-yanari' did this seemingly random timeout stop occurring.

I'm not suggestion you start paying $200/mo as a solution.  You can get to near zero with a few suggestions below. Tuning concurrency, db connection, and experimenting with various options like timeouts take some trail and error - as there seems to be no plug-and-chug formula to give you a perfect combination for all these parameters.

1) Move to Unicorn to take more control of your processes and database connections. Here is a sample unicorn.rb file https://gist.github.com/blotto/8005531b9c94f3732240

2) Increase your timeouts ( currently 5 seconds ).  See unicorn.rb :

```
 timeout ENV['REQUEST_TIMEOUT'].to_i > 0 ?  ENV['REQUEST_TIMEOUT'].to_i : 15
```

3) Be sure you're on the latest stable Rails 4.1.1. As 4.0.x did have some Postgres adaptor issues. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12867

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ENV['REQUEST_TIMEOUT'].to_i > 5` instead?

Comment: @Tamer , no - that condition simply tests if that env var exists or not. `nil.to_i == 0`.  so this ensures the timeout setting has a valid default