# Restart rails app automatically after a crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 4 app hosted on heroku ( cedar stack ), which crashes sometimes.

Is it possible to automatically restart the server whenever this happen?

Usually I do it manually with `heroku restart` but... hey I'm not in front of a console 24/7!

Comment: sounds like you should fix the bug which crashes the app :)

Comment: Of course we cannot understand how to fix it! Have a look here if you'd like to help us: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24067676/396133