# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError w/ rails, sidekiq & postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, sidekiq

I have a rails application that is running postgresql and sidekiq. When scheduling a large amount of background jobs that take ~20 seconds each to complete I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.097 seconds)
```

In my `database.yml` file I have specified a pool of `100`. Then in my postgres config I have set the `max_connections` to be `200` (as there are other applications using postgres). It seems like this should avoid this problem but it does not.

Ideas?

Comment: check out my answer here - it has some useful information on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067676/rails-4-connectiontimeouterror-on-heroku-basic-plan/24146836#24146836